# Different styles in fullscreen mode using react-image-gallery

Tags: css, reactjs

How can I to have different styles for fullscreen mode in [react-image-gallery](https://github.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery)?

I have created custom image class using `originalClass`

```
.imageSlider {
  width: 430px;
  max-height: 480px;
}
```

but in fullscreen mode `max-height` rule also appears

Answer (score 1):

Add the class `.fullscreen`

```css
/*
class for normal
*/
.imageSlider {
  width: 430px;
  max-height: 480px;
}
/*
class for fullscreen
*/
.fullscreen .imageSlider {
  width: 430px;
  max-height: 480px;
}
```